# Reading serialized C++ structs in C# using BinaryReader

Tags: c#, c++, serialization, struct, packing

I've got a few files that have been serialized by directly writing C++ `struct`s using a binary `fstream`. Now, when I generate the read methods for corresponding C# classes, I find out that these don't really map 1-to-1, probably because of structure packing.

So my question is - what is the best way to handle the situation? I've got both C++ and C# source code, so I can change either part. Should I attempt to serialize C++ without packing (I assume this is done with `#pragma pack(1)`, right) or instead somehow adjust my C# code to take account of the gaps?

Or is the problem with deserializing completely different and nothing to do with packing?

**Update 1** I discovered that C++ `enum`s are 4 bytes long and `bool` values are 2 bytes long (who knew?), but even after adding `#pragma pack(1)` I am only able to correctly read the first record. Also, I've checked the number of bytes against `sizeof(MyStructure)` and the values match. This must mean that there is some padding between the records.

**Update 2** Darn, found a bug in code. Copy-paste error. Need PVS Studio or something. All good now. (And yeah, a boolean is 1 byte big.)

Comment: enums are not necessarily 4 bytes and bool is not necessarily 2 bytes. It depends on your platform and compiler. (I know that's not helpful here, but I need to point it out so that other people don't get the wrong idea from reading this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alignment is the likely cause of the problem.

Structure packing/byte alignment is compiler implementation dependent, and also varies with the build target to optimise for the hardware in question. This means it would be wise not to rely on a given set of structure alignments that your compiler happens to produce for a given build.

If you need to share structures reliably, it would be best to `#pragma pack(1)` and add the padding back in manually if performance is an issue. This is only likely to be a concern if the structures are used in a tight inner loop.

An example of manual alignment:

```
struct Record {
    char c;
    char __padding[7];
    double d;
};
```

Your C# code would then look something like:

```
this.c = reader.ReadChar();
reader.ReadBytes(7); // or reader.BaseStream.Seek(7, SeekOrigin.Current);
this.d = reader.ReadDouble();
```

Comment: Actually, it turns out that it's not just packing but also size of variables. Who knew that `bool` values take up 2 bytes?